# Split string to array

Tags: php

I am trying to get remainder value using php:

```
Example:
$string1 ="1477014108152000180343081299001";
$string2 ="1731731731731731731731731731731";
```

Each digit of $string1 is multiplied by each digit of $string2

```
$string1 = 1 4 7 7 0 1 4 1 0 8 1 5 2 0 0 0 1 8 0 3 4 3 0 8 1 2 9 9 0 0 1
           * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
$string2=  1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1 7 3 1
```

Starting from the front of the string
    Sum=1 + 28 + 21 + 7 + 0 + 3 + 4 + 7 + 0 + 8 + 7 + 15 + 2 + 0 +0 + 0 + 7 + 24 + 0 + 21 + 12 + 3 + 0 + 24 + 1 + 14 +27 +9 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 246

```
Remainder = 246 % 10= 6
```

I want to create array of $string1 and $string2, so that I can easily multiply each value. Please help me to split $string1 and $string2 in to array.

I want array as below:

$array=array('1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1','7','3','1');

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032674/string-to-array-and-back

Comment: Thanks sdolgy, this looks great and it will work perfectly...

Comment: use str_split as @Darhazer has suggested.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Answer (score 2):

you can access to string characters as to array elements:

```
for ($i=0, $c=strlen($string1); $i<$c; $i++) 
  echo("char number $i is ". $string1[$i]);
```

Comment: of course, there are lot ways of optimization, i've just shown the way how to access string elements without using specific functions for converting the string to array

Comment: i also did not understand the downvote. can you explain (addressing to its author)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, what you are going to achieve, there is no reason to split the strings, before processing

```
$size = strlen($string1);
$sum = 0; 
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
  $sum += $string1[$i] * $string2[$i];
```

or (only looking at the remainder)

```
$size = strlen($string1);
$remainder = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++)
  $remainder = ($remaider + $string1[$i] * $string2[$i]) % 10;
```

The last one is definitly prefered, because you can assume, that the sum will grow very large

Answer (score -2):

You can do this using preg_match_all:

```
$string1 ="1477014108152000180343081299001";
$string2 ="1731731731731731731731731731731";  

$val = array();
$count = preg_match_all('/\d/', $string1, &$val);
$array1 = $val[0];

$val = array();
$count = preg_match_all('/\d/', $string2, &$val);
$array1 = $val[0];
```

Comment: An interesting approach but really not recommended.

Comment: Will not work: e.g. `$val` is never used before its assigned to `$array1`, whereas `array1` is (propably accidentally) used twice.