# Compose a string from array elements say index 1 and index 7 sperated by a period

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have made a `String[]` array by using `String.split(".")`. I am now trying to make a new `String` out of this array, but with only the `Strings` at specific indexes of the array. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your problem. The thing about indexes 1 and 7 might have gotten me confused. Could you please elaborate and maybe provide a working example?

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032674/string-to-array-and-back

Comment: What is the question? What have you tried? Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: The question is #2 How do I make a string out of the array seperated by a period like this:  John.Doe.G  Lastname.FirstName.MiddleName.     Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] arr = myString.split(".");
int[] indices = { 1, 7 };
int length = indices.length;

StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    str.append(arr[indices[i]]);
    if (i+1 != length) str.append(".");
}

String result = str.toString();
```

Comment: this will result in an additional "." at the end. I don't know if that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Alex, the first line String[] arr = myString.split(".");  do I need this as I have already split my orginal string into the array.

Comment: no i was just doing that for your own reference... in other words, the array `arr` is your array that contains the words you've split.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println(arry[0] + "." + arry[6]);
```

Edit for persisting to variable, rather than displaying:

```
String a = "a";
String b = "b";
String both = a + "." + b;
```

Comment: You might want to add, that it's due to the fact that in Java arrays start with an index of 0, so the first element has the index 0, the 7th has index 6, and the Nth has index N-1

Comment: Thanks Bleam, I also need the string to be stored in a variable. So that I can pass it along. No need to print to screen.

Comment: Yes, this is true @Grove. In all programming languages that come to mind, arrays begin at index 0 for the first element.

Comment: @blearn the pascal developer in me tends to disagree, but that's not the issue here

Comment: Whoa, whoa...easy tigers.  I apologize for and retract my previous comment.